# Making an argument required if generic interface as no properties

Tags: typescript

How can I make a function argument required based on whether or not `P` has any properties besides `onClose`.

So:

- If type `P` has properties besides `onClose`, `props` needs to be required and equal to `Omit<P, 'onClose'>`
- If type `P` has **no** properties besides onClose, `props` should not be allowed

```
export interface Closeable {
  onClose: () => void
}

export type WindowOpenFunction = <P extends Closeable>(
  window: ComponentType<P>,
  props: Omit<P, 'onClose'>
) => void
```

Comment: What's `ComponentType`? Do we have to worry about that? It would be nice if this were a [mre] without any distractions. If I make a random guess about `ComponentType` then I get [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1QQAw). Does that work for you? If so I could write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: ComponentType is a react type, but someone else provided an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a way to do it by using spread arguments. First we got to find a way to detect if P has no properties besides onClose.

```
keyof Omit<P, 'onClose'> extends never
```

means that there's no extra key inside P besides onClose.

Then we can use a type condition to to do the job:

```
export type WindowOpenFunction = <P extends Closeable>(
  window: P,
  ...args: keyof Omit<P, 'onClose'> extends never ? 
    [] | [undefined] | [Omit<P, 'onClose'>]: [Omit<P, 'onClose'>]
) => void
```

If props has no extra props then the list of extra arguments can either be an empty tuple of one argument or a tuple of one argument, otherwise, it needs to be a tuple of one argument.

Comment: `keyof X extends []` is bizarre.  `keyof` anything will be a subtype of `string | number | symbol`.  It can never be `[]`.  I suppose `keyof X extends []` is effectively `keyof X extends never`, but the former is more confusing.  Do you want to change it to `keyof X extends never` instead?

Comment: You're right, I thought for a second keyof would be a type of an array of all the keys. Oddly enough it seems to work correctly with this but i'll edit

Comment: It works because `never` is a universal subtype, so if `keyof X extends never` then `keyof X` also trivially extends `[]`.  And since there's no overlap between `string | number | symbol` and `[]`, then there's no way to have `keyof X extends []` unless `keyof X` is `never`.  So I could imagine using it as a terser form, but it's not idiomatic.

Comment: This appears to work. I tweaked it `...args: keyof Omit<P, 'onClose'> extends never ? [] : [Omit<P, 'onClose'>]` because this appears to *prevent* extra or unnecessary args, it limits it either to no args, or only those allowed.